# Can't get my TableView to work

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, tableview

'Can't get this to work at all ! I had a nice simple class for a TableView that took up the entire screen, but decided i'd slice it in half, so the table only took the top half of the screen. This is my code:

This is the TableSplitViewController.h

```
 @interface TableSplitViewController : UIViewController
{
    ChildrenTableViewController *firstController;
    IBOutlet UITableView *firstTable;

}
```

This is the TableSplitViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  { 
[super viewDidLoad];
if (firstController == nil) {
    firstController = [[ChildrenTableViewController alloc] init];
}
    [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
    [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
    firstController.view = firstController.tableView;

 }
```

This is the ChildrenTableViewController.h:

```
@interface ChildrenTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *childname;

@end
```

This is the ChildrenTableViewController.m:

```
    @implementation ChildrenTableViewController

         @synthesize childname;



  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
  {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
 }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.childname = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"Oliver",
                      @"Stuart",
                      @"Ross",
                      @"Alex", nil];
}

   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowChildrenDetails"]) {
            ChildrenDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue     destinationViewController];

          NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

          detailViewController.childrenDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                                    initWithObjects: [self.childname  objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]], nil];
     }
  }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }



  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
  } 

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {

      // Return the number of rows in the section.
      return [self.childname count];
  }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"childrenTablecell";

      ChildrenTableViewCell * cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[ChildrenTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       }
      // Configure the cell..
      cell.childname.text = [self.childname objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    return cell;
}
```

This is ChildrenTableViewCell.h:

```
@interface ChildrenTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *childname;

@end
```

This is ChildrenTableViewCell.m:

```
@implementation ChildrenTableViewCell

@synthesize childname;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

This is a print screen of the storyboard layout.  I've attached the label with the childname so it should print the name out :

[image: Screenshot 1]

This is a print screen of it running, its weird it has the 4 rows, i can select them, but the labels are not being printed :

![Screenshot 2][2]

Fully appreciate all the help and support you can provide.  Thanks :)

[2]http://puu.sh/1USzX/512ede1328

Thanks to IOSDEV i managed to find out why it was doing it.

```
cell.childname.text = [self.childname objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSLog(@"%@",[self.childname objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
NSLog(@"%@",cell.childname.text);
```

This is what i put into my code.

and this is what i got:

```
2013-01-30 15:33:52.465 TableViewStory[17509:907] Oliver
2013-01-30 15:33:52.467 TableViewStory[17509:907] (null)
2013-01-30 15:33:52.470 TableViewStory[17509:907] Stuart
2013-01-30 15:33:52.472 TableViewStory[17509:907] (null)
2013-01-30 15:33:52.473 TableViewStory[17509:907] Ross
2013-01-30 15:33:52.474 TableViewStory[17509:907] (null)
2013-01-30 15:33:52.476 TableViewStory[17509:907] Alex
2013-01-30 15:33:52.477 TableViewStory[17509:907] (null)
```

So as you can see cell.childname.text is equal to null, this is the reason why the text isn't coming up :P  I don't understand why it is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the initWithStyle in the TableSplitViewController.m

```
firstController = [[ChildrenTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

For some reason when I didn't use it to init the tableView I had some similar problems.

Comment: Tried it and made no difference :(  Thanks though :)

Comment: You have set the parent as the source and delegate so I think you should move the array of data to the parent or remove the set delegate and source from the parent as the child controller is UITableViewController and it's doesn't need to be set as delegate and source.

Comment: Done what IOS DEV said and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: try to print to the log the label. and try to put breakpoints in the cellForRow maybe something is overriding the label text and put nothing instead as you can press on it and see the content on the right

Comment: Okay, now were onto something here.  This is what i put into the code:    cell.childname.text = [self.childname objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.childname objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.childname.text);

AND This is the outcome:

Oliver
(null)
Stuart
(null)
Ross
(null)
Alex
(null)

so for some reason the text inside the childname label isn't being saved.  I don't understand why :S  The outcome will come back in this comment i'll just edit the question

Comment: Okay found out what it was.  I forgot to put in the identifier -.-  I make some stupid mistakes sometimes.  Thanks anyway :)